# Is there a way to get Postman to import OpenAPI specs automatically after a local build?

Tags: postman, openapi

I am developing a REST API using C#/ASP .NET Core. As part of this, I am using Swagger to generate OpenAPI specifications to represent all of the models and endpoints that this API exposes.

When I want to test these endpoints locally using Postman, I need to go through the process of opening the web browser to `https://localhost:xxxx/swagger/v1/swagger.json` to access the spec, I then need to copy it, go to Postman and follow `Collections -> Import -> Raw text -> paste -> Continue`. Then I need to set the global collection variables like the URL over and over as it's wiped every time a new collection is imported.

This gets **very** arduous when you are making quick small changes that need to be tested.

Is there any way to get Postman to automatically update its copy of a collection when a new local build of the ASP .NET Core solution succeeds? Or the reverse - somehow getting Visual Studio to 'push' the updated local spec to Postman?

I know this may be a stretch, just wondering if anyone else has come across this problem before. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to do it automatically, but copying the raw text is needlessly complicating yourself when you can just point Postman to the link to swagger.json (Collections -> Import -> Link)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes that just occurred to me while I was scouring Postman for other options - that does shave some time off. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. I have never registered to use "Workspaces" (supposedly free) but that might have what you're after